# jquery: undefined value when accessing item on json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to learn jquery here so I took a regular javascript snippet that loops through a json collection like this:

```
 for (var i in msg) {
                        alert(msg[i].Name);
                    }
```

In this case, the alert box displays the correct name.

However, if I use jquery like this:

```
  $.each(msg, function(item) {
                        alert(item.Name);
                    });
```

alert box show undefined for each item in the json collection.  What did I miss?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second parameter.

```
  // this one-------------v
$.each(msg, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.Name);
});
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried something like that but still got undefined... anyways, works now,  thanks again.